# Synchronization of multiple task writing to file

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-6.0

I want to run multiple tasks that do something and append a line to file, hence I need to synchronize the file access part. I implemented it like this using *SemaphoreSlim*:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
public static async Task WriteToFile(string path)
{
    await DoSomething();
    try
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        await using StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path, true); // append
        await outputFile.WriteAsync("I'm a very long string for file, abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh");
        outputFile.Close(); // it is necessary to close before releasing of the semaphore
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }

    await DoAnotherThing();
}
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            tasks.Add(WriteToFile("testing.txt"));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but are there caveats, or maybe, there's a better solution?

Comment: You are not doing any exception handling. For your little console application here it probably doesn't matter, but if anything related to opening or writing to the StreamWriter throws an exception, `_semaphore.Release()` won't be invoked anymore, thus deadlocking everything waiting on the release of the semaphore. The code section(s) safeguarded by the semaphore should be put in a `try`-`finally`with the semaphore being realease in the `finally`-block...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Good point! I've updated the code. Anything else?

Comment: The usage of `StreamWriter` can be simplified to just calling `File.AppendAllLinesAsync()` or `File.AppendAllTextAsync()`, or you could pass a `StreamWriter` to [`TextWriter.Synchronized()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.synchronized), share that among your tasks, and then drop the explicit synchronization with the semaphore. This is a very open question, though, with no clearly-defined problem. Instead of starting with this minimal code and making piecemeal improvements, have you looked at questions about sharing a resource among `Task`s? I'm sure there's plenty.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews thank you for the TextWriter.Synchronized tip